# Mac O Linker errors with Tesseract

Tags: swift, xcode, tesseract

I have a simple Swift iOS project created in Xcode 8.1 and added Tesseract Framework. I am getting

> clang: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input

There is no help on Google about this error. Can someone explain what this error means. I have **-lstdc++** and **-$(inherited)** in my other linker flags. If I try to add **-E** flag it gives me a

> Found an unexpected MAch-O header code: 0x20312023

Comment: Can you show what the command looks like that causes that error (from the Report Navigator)?  There might be a stray hyphen somewhere confusing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was wrong version of `TesseractOCR.frmaework` generated earlier (probably for simulator). Fixed it by regenerating the framework and replacing it in the project.